# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string #2

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlparameter

Here's my code:

```
DateTime Dob = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1800");
DateTime Dod = Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1800");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.birthday))
     Dob = Convert.ToDateTime(p.birthday);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.deathday))
     Dod = Convert.ToDateTime(p.deathday);

string query = string.Format("insert into actor values (@name, @biography, @placeOfBirth, @profilePath, @dob, @dod)");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.name) ? p.name : "not available"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@biography", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.biography) ? p.biography : "not available"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@placeOfBirth", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.place_of_birth) ? p.place_of_birth : "not available"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@profilePath", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.profile_path) ? p.profile_path : "not available"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dob", Dob));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dod", Dod));

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error I get is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

The values for Dod and Dob are below:

[image]

[image]

**QUESTION**: Is there something wrong with my `DateTime` objects that SQL doesn't like?  If not, what's going on????

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on the ordinal position of your columns... and it could be that those differ from the order of the corresponding values. You might try explicitly naming your target columns. I'm guessing at the column names here.

```
insert into actor 
(Name, Biography, PlaceOfBirth, ProfilePath, DoB, DoD)
values 
(@name, @biography, @placeOfBirth, @profilePath, @dob, @dod)
```

Comment: @MikeMarks how'd that go?